# Can't preview SSRS report in VS2013?

Tags: reporting-services

I've created a new "Report Server Project" in VS2013 .Net 4.5. I've added a data source and the test connection succeeds. I've added a DataSet using the "Use a dataset embedded in my report" option choosing the data source previously created. The query type is Stored Procedure with a single text parameter. In the report data box I can right click my DataSet, choose Query, and execute the sproc. I see a grid populated correctly with my data.

However, when I try to create and preview a report it fails. I do the following:

1. Add a new report.
2. Drop a table on it from the toolbox.
3. Start dragging fields from my DataSet onto the table.
4. When I hit preview I see the following
   [image]

Here is the text that gets spit into the output window:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The
>   communication object,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel, cannot
>   be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.BeginSend(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.BeginRequest(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartSend(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishEnsureOpen(IAsyncResult
>   result, Boolean completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartEnsureOpen(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishEnsureInteractiveInit(IAsyncResult
>   result, Boolean completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartEnsureInteractiveInit()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.Begin()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginCall(String
>   action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeBeginService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.IPreviewProcessing.BeginSetItemPath(String
>   itemPath, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.PreviewProcessingClient.BeginSetItemPath(String
>   itemPath, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.WCFProcessingHost.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(AsyncCallback
>   ac, Object s)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.WCFProcessingHost.<>c__DisplayClass3b.b__39()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.WCFProcessingHost.ExecuteWcfCall(Action
>   wcfCall)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.WCFProcessingHost.ExecuteAsyncCall(Func`3
>   beginAction, AsyncCallback endAction)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.WCFProcessingHost.set_ItemContext(PreviewItemContext
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.ChangeReportDefinition(DefinitionSource
>   updatingSourceType, Action changeAction)    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.set_ReportPath(String value) 
>   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.PreviewFrame.RefreshPreview()

I have googled for two days with no luck, any help is much appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**
It turns out, when you preview the report, this console window opens. I must have closed it the first time, then the preview fails. If you leave the console window open the preview works fine. Here is a screenshot so you can see what I'm talking about. In order to get previewing to work, I just had to re-start visual studio and make sure not to close the console window when it pops up when I hit preview.

[image]

Comment: I answered my own question in the edited comment, hooray!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a reported bug in SSDT-BI. In the meantime the current workaround is to right click on the report you want to preview in your Solution Explorer and click RUN and it will work unless you want to keep that command prompt window open.

Comment: Can you please provide a link?

Answer (score 1):

Running the Microsoft Visual Studio as Administrator will resolve this issue.